# paragraph one line with text box HTML

Tags: html, css, textbox, alignment

> [text box] submit.............................................[p]welcome bla bla bla

I'm trying to arrange my text box with my welcome text in my website

the welcome text is in paragraph and i try to use align right but the paragraph is in the below of my text box

here is my code

```
<div class="signupParent">
    <div id="signupInner">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="subsemail">
        <input type="button" value="Subscribe">
    </form>
    <p id="welcome">Welcome to Promochan. Sign In || Register</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.signupParent{
    background-color: #E3E6FF;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#signupInner{
    display: table-cell;

}

#welcome{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
```

anyone can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` and `form` are `block` elements. Make them `inline-block` or `float` them.

Write:

```
form,#welcome{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9jUw/) here.

Comment: do not use form, #welcome. This will tell all forms to display inline-block and you may not want that.

Answer (score 0):

add `inline-block;` for `#welcome` and `form`

```
    form,#welcome{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/3737q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` and `<p>` is a block elements, which has a line break before and after it. You can change this behavior by apply

```
form, p{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rk828/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You actually want this:

```
#signupInner form,#welcome{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Notice the "#signupInner form" sets ONLY that form to display inline-block